# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load jQuery into content script when page is loaded.

All works great until couple days ago when some users started to get errors.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I was thinking what can cause this problem, because all works great.

**Part of manifest file:**

```
"content_scripts": [
{
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": [
        "js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    ],
    "css": [
        "css/overlay.css"
    ],
    "matches": [
        "https://coolsite.com/*"
    ],
    "runAt": "document_start"
},
{
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": [
        "content/content1.js"
    ],
    "matches": [
        "https://coolsite.com/*",
    ],
    "runAt": "document_end"
}]
```

**Code of content1.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Broadcast runner loaded
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        callback: true,
        runnerLoaded: true
    });
});
```

The problem is something about jQuery, couldn't find out why.
I will be so thankful for some help.

Thank you,
Ori

Comment: give a bigger part... is it in "content scripts" ? and where is that code?

Comment: @FlashThunder Thank you, just updated.
Any idea?

Comment: it's really hard to tell without the full code